# Why do most microwaves open from the right to the left?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, kitchen

Why do all of the microwaves that are used in our houses opening from the right side to left side? I've never seen any that do the opposite. I called LG company and asked them why and I got an answer in a week by email indicating that the first design that they did was in this structure and style.

[image]

Comment: http://refrigerators.reviewed.com/features/ask-the-experts-why-do-microwaves-open-right-to-left

Comment: Actually, many microwaves open from the top 
https://www.google.com/search?q=drop+down+door+microwave&tbm=isch

Comment: @wim I have never seen one of those in the U.S.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, they're mostly used in restaurant or expensive houses

Comment: I think microwaves should have automatic doors that close when they start cooking, and open when they stop.  I see no benefit in having the door closed when cooking is not actually in progress.

Comment: @DavidWallace What if I leave the micro on and go away of the room, and someone puts something in front of it (lets say waiting to be heated), an automatic opening could be "dangerous".

Comment: I wondered this myself too, already. It's quite a pain in our kitchen where the microwave is installed on the far right of a shelf and when opening it the door is in the way of putting something in or getting something out.

Comment: @Alvaro I was imagining doors that slide open, or possibly even open like an iris.  I wasn't imagining doors that hinge outwards like the current generation of microwave doors do.

Comment: @CandiedOrange See my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidWallace That sort of door would be difficult to shield effectively.

Comment: @DavidWallace *"I see no benefit in having the door closed when cooking is not actually in progress."* Adopt a couple of sheddy cats and see if your feeling on that changes!

Comment: Might as well argue that all cupboard doors should be left open at all times. Or why give cupboards doors at all?

Comment: We have a Siemens microwave that opens from the left, because it fits better with place in the kitchen (it is on the right of one of the walls). It was not so easy to find. There is also a similar Bosch microwave. I think they are essentially the same but with a different exterior design. This is in Europe, I don't know if they are available in other parts of the world.

Comment: My parents have an extra-wide microwave that you can open from either side.  Just not both at once (not that I tried very hard...)

Comment: @Devin Must be nice to be unconscientious enough to actually buy one of those. From the looks of those pictures I am starting to wonder if your definition of microwave is the same as OP's. Most of those seem to be convection ovens or "toaster ovens" as the pragmatic people would call it.

Comment: I recall that early microwaves opened from the top like the old oven. But when the interlock failed and it killed someone opening it, they decided to not aim the beam at the operator’s head.

Comment: I instantly checked my microwave after reading this question.

Comment: I have no where in my kitchen where I can place the microwave & safely load & empty my microwave with the left opening door. I have hand some accidents with hot food & plates trying to negotiate this awkward opening.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Because the control panel is on the right.**

Microwaves have the controls on the right to favour right handed people (similar to the placement of control panels on pre 1990's televisions.)

Placing the hinge on the right would make for a very awkward design as it would be near the middle. If you wanted to stir your food and adjust the controls at the same time, you would find the door bashing into your arm. Having it on the left means it is at one end of the equipment, so when the door is open there is no obstruction for an operator moving between controls and food.

Comment: I would say one thing goes together with the other. The control is on the right + the door opens from the right for right handed. For left handed it would be left control + door opening from left to right.

Comment: From a technical point of view, this is probably the correct answer. If in doubt, go to your microwave, and imagine the door opening left to right (with controls on the right). The right side of the door would collide with the control zone, so you wouldn't be able to open the door. Thus: the hinge has to be on the most external side. After that, it's just a numbers game: 90% of people is right handed, so... controls on the right.

Comment: Do you normally use the controls without first shutting the door? My microwave actually resets the clock when I close the door so it's not even possible (unless it's just the time remaining when I opened the door).

Comment: *"... mirroring the placement of control panels ..."* does this mean control panels are on opposite side as older TV's? Shouldn't this say "... duplicating the placement of control panels ..."?

Comment: This answer, as written, boils down to "they are laid out how they are because they have the layout they have"; if the hinge was on the right, the control panel could go on the left, problem solved. With some tweaking, it could answer the related question of why they don't have *easily reversible* doors, like many refrigerators do. Converting a microwave would be more like converting a car dashboard between left- and right-hand drive: it would require significant rearrangement of components.

Comment: Who stirs their food and adjusts the microwave controls at the same time?

Comment: In addition to the open door being awkward if the hinge were next to the control panel, you'd also have to either separate the door release mechanism from the control panel (so that it was next to the latch) or have a long series of levers running from the control panel side of the door to the latch side of the door (increasing the chances of a part breaking).  The fact that most microwaves (especially early microwaves) have a mechanical release for the door constrains your options quite a bit.

Answer (score 112):

I would guess it's because **the design fits better for right-handed people**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness): "Studies suggest that 88–92% of the world population is right-handed".

Microwave doors open such so that the user can insert dishes and glassware with the right hand, while holding the door with the left hand if necessary. The user needs more precision to control that which is being inserted. Afterwards, the user can close the door with either hand.

#### Edit

With a microwave, we are managing hot foods and drinks. Extra safety and precision are important.

It's true that a right-handed person can successfully handle dishes using the left hand.  But a cup, for example, certainly could use more skill — especially if it contains a hot drink.

Comment: so people who are right-handed by nature is more luckily than people who are left-handed. So it is not fair to just produce a microwaves that is designed to right-handed. I think both of design have to be considered :)

Comment: 90% of the population are right-handed, so it makes business sense to only make right-handed microwaves, and let the lefties adapt.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 I would think someone would jump in to sell to the remaining 10%. That is a big extra market share.

Comment: @Hennes Microwaves are rarely used by just one person.

Comment: Then why many refrigerators open from the left to the right?

Comment: @user23013: most fullsize fridges have hinges that can be installed on either side, so the door opening can work with the cabinetry/room layout of the kitchen they are installed into.

Comment: Fridges have their internal mechanism at the top and behind the fridge area, so, being symmetrical, it's rather easy to attach hinges to both sides. Microwave ovens very typically have their control panel and attached circuitry on their side.

Comment: But there are many appliances especially for left-handed people. Scissors, ehm... and all the other appliances I can't think up examples for. So, why not manufacture left-handed microwaves? With the right advertising campaign, you could make serious money.

Comment: I've cleared out many of these comments. Please don't use the comment option for extended discussion, take that to [CHAT] instead.

Comment: @MrLister My wife is left-handed. We don't mind having an extra pair of scissors, but we don't feel like putting an extra microwave in our kitchen.

Comment: @Ra'adBin The world isn't about fairness, its about what makes money, and nobody wants to buy a microwave suited for only 10% of the population. You are welcome to fund your own efforts into providing this product to the open market, though.

Comment: If you could sell left-handed microwaves at 30% margin instead of right-handed ones at 3% you would make the same money out of 1/10 as many appliances. So I imagine that the lefties are unwilling to pay about one-third more for a left-handed microwave. (Or, has nobody ever tried to sell this model? ) Scissors are much less expensive and much harder to use with the wrong hand.

Answer (score 5):

I think making a microwave door hinge at the bottom center (like that of a conventional oven) would solve the right-hand / left-hand argument.

Also: We are trained to move left to right, mainly because that is how most of us read and write.  Therefore, if the keypad was on the left, that would suggest that you would have to key in the settings before inserting the food.

Comment: A downward-opening door would cause other problems. Many microwaves sit on counter-tops, so the hinges would have to be mounted high enough to allow the door to open without being fouled by the counter. That would waste vertical space by forcing the oven to be on little legs or something. For microwaves mounted higher than counter-height, a downward-opening door would obstruct entry to the oven.

Comment: Next to that, plenty of microwaves (at least in my country) are placed on top of another object. With a door that opens downwards, you might think it's a good idea to use it as a temporary table to put your food on while you grab some gloves or other equipment. until the entire thing topples over, that is.

Comment: My microwave is hung above the stove. With a door opening downwards, I would need to reach above the door into a microwave that I now can't see to get my food. Sounds like a good way to get burned.

Comment: There are many microwaves that have a downward opening  door

Comment: @DavidRicherby A counter-example: Many (most?) toaster ovens have downward opening doors and sit on counter tops and tables. 
(Though they are usually smaller, and often the door can be supported when open by the handle resting on the counter.)

Comment: @LindsayMorsillo, most toaster ovens need an air gap between the bottom of the oven and whatever surface it's on, to prevent heat damage.  Since you already need the higher hinge point, there's no penalty to a downward-opening door.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, they wouldn't be mounted that way if they'd always opened downward.

Comment: @LindsayMorsillo Microwave ovens need thick doors because the door needs to contain shielding to keep the microwaves inside. Toaster oven doors only need to be a sheet of glass, so need a much thinner hinge. (By the way, "counter-example" -- deliberate pun? :-) )

Comment: At the "Subway" brand of sandwich shop in the US, they have "Toasting Ovens" to quickly heat the food with convection. They look like a large commercial microwave oven and the door opens downward. Other than that, I have never seen anything except a toaster oven (and standard range oven, obviously) open downward. Well, clothes dryer... Cars used to have rear doors that opened downward: the now outmoded "Station Wagon".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Incidentally I have the same problem with side hinges - the door does not open properly without pulling the microwave oven out slightly away from the wall.

Comment: @immibis " Well, they wouldn't be mounted that way if they'd always opened downward." Exactly. Allow me to rephrase what you wrote: a downwards opening door is less flexible than a sideways-opening door, because it means you can mount the oven in fewer places. This would be a bad thing.

Comment: Re: `"primarily because that is how we read and write"`. That explains why all microwaves in Asia and in the Middle East open on the left. Oh, wait... :)

Comment: I own a microwave with a downward opening door. It looks like this: http://eco-dream.co.jp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ot007.jpg

Comment: You are all discussing physical problems related to the environment the appliance is placed. Don't forget about the person using it. My grandmother specifically wanted an oven that opened as a microwave (side hinges) as a door with hinges at the bottom means she has to reach further to get food in and out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing it as a question of hinge. In my opinion it is a question of control.

As some other person has noted, the majority of old TV sets, even before remotes,  have had the control knobs to the right.

It is control which commends design. Microwaves operations demand visual perception plus hand manipulation; 90% of population is right handed; so, in order to not interfere vision and hand operation, right side controls seem logical.

As a left handed person I know the feeling of misfitting in a right handed world, anyway these obstacles it are not -usually- life threatening issues :-)

PS TV sets abandoned this design when remotes became the norm.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's simply due to biased assumption that most people are right handed and kitchens have been designed to accommodate the "standard" design.

Some have a reversable door. Some have pull-out doors. Some have a top-open door. Few are designed with a "left access design". They can be, but they just are not. Yes, this makes it inconvenient for everyone, not just left-handers, who have a microwave up against a fridge, or wall or a counter-top obstructing the right side.

Comment: It's not a biased assumption, it's a fact that ~90% of the people are right-handed. (Lefty here BTW.)